# How to make side-positioned label's width adjustable based on largest size in FormLayout in Vaadin Flow?

Tags: forms, layout, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin flow, the item labels in FormLayout can be sided by using addFormItem:

```
formLayout.addFormItem(referenceNumber, "Reference Number");
formLayout.addFormItem(invoices, "Invoices");
```

The side-positioned label's width is fixed. How to make label size auto adjust based on the longest label? The label with of the above example should be the length of "Reference Number";

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do that because the labels do not have any connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish this by using CSS grid. It’s going to be a bit hacky, and use unsupported CSS selectors, but it is doable.

You need a custom theme, where you add these style sheets to the `frontend/themes/mytheme/components/` folder.

vaadin-form-layout.css:

```css
#layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
  grid-column-gap: var(--vaadin-form-layout-column-spacing);
  --vaadin-form-item-label-width: auto;
}
```

vaadin-form-item.css:

```css
:host {
  display: contents;
}

#spacing {
  display: none;
}
```

Follow-up question from comments:

> My application has formlayouts with both top-positioned and side-positioned label. The css affects both. How can we make it affect only formlayout with side-positioned label?

You can add a class name to the Form Layouts that need side-positioned labels:

```java
formLayout.addClassName("side-aligned-labels");
```

vaadin-form-layout.css:

```css
:host(.side-aligned-labels) #layout {
  /* Others as before, then add the following: */
  --vaadin-form-item-display: contents;
  --vaadin-form-item-spacing-display: none;
}
```

vaadin-form-item.css:

```css
:host {
  display: var(--vaadin-form-item-display);
}

#spacing {
  display: var(--vaadin-form-item-spacing-display);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jouni. This works fine after moving "--vaadin-form-item-label-width: auto;" from #layout in vaadin-form-layout.css to host in vaadin-form-item.css. My application has formlayouts with  both top-positioned and side-positioned label. The css affects both. How can we make it affect only formlayout with side-positioned label?

Comment: I updated the answer with a follow-up.

Comment: Hi Jouni, the solution works fine if we have only one column. How can I make it work for multiple columns? ie, make formlayout.setResponsiveSteps work. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, I think you need to have fixed widths for the labels, instead of letting the longest label decide the width of the label column (so back to square one). Once browsers have CSS subgrid support (https://caniuse.com/css-subgrid), that restriction doesn't apply anymore.

That, or you need to calculate the label width using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Jouni. In Vaadin 8, GridLayout allows to have multiple columns and width of each column is determined by longest labels in that column. Do you have any suggestions for implementing a flow GridLayout?

Comment: You could try this add-on: https://vaadin.com/directory-beta/addon/gridlayout - note that if you use regular text in place of proper field labels, you should take care of screen reader accessibility by setting the same text as the `aria-label` attribute of the field component.